# issue in reading rss feed using java

Tags: java, rss

Hie

I tried to follow [vogella](http://www.vogella.de/articles/RSSFeed/article.html)

and when i use a rss feed it throws following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,50]
Message: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
    at vik.tools.changeNotifier.RSSFeedParser.readFeed(RSSFeedParser.java:131)
    at vik.tools.changeNotifier.ReadTest.main(ReadTest.java:6)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,50]
Message: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:85)
    at vik.tools.changeNotifier.RSSFeedParser.readFeed(RSSFeedParser.java:61)
```

Any advise on this please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok looks like issue was with rss url itself. i tested with other frameworks and rss reader codes and i got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

because this is not a rss page. it's an html page. a css page would be, for example, http://www.vogella.de/article.rss .

Comment: no i did not read that page. i said i referred that code. I tried to use a rss feed source.

Comment: then you should show your code, because, with the informations you've provided, I can only say that the rss you're trying to reach is malformed.

Comment: well mozilla correctly identify that url as a valid rss and shows data as well.

Comment: really? I guess it only shows data. firefox corrects a lot of things. Well, without your code we can't help you very much.

Comment: i copy pasted the code as it is on the link posted in my original question and just used my rss url.